# Mostrar nombres en un input evitando que se repita

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel

El problema es que estoy realizando un formulario y en el `input` del nombre estoy ejecutando un autocomplete con `javascript` en el que muestra los nombres en la base de datos pero el problema esta en que los nombres se repiten y lo ideal seria que si 2 o mas registros tienen el mismo nombre al menos aparezca 1 y no doy con la solucion de este problema.

este es el codigo de la vista:

```
<form class="row g-3" action="{{route('cuentas.store')}}" method="POST">
<div class="container">
    @csrf
<div class="row justify-content-md-center">
    <div class="col-md-2">
        <label class="form-label">Fecha</label>
        <input type="date" name="fecha" class="form-control">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
        <label class="form-label">Nombre</label>
        <input type="text" name="nombre" id="nombre" class="form-control">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
        <label class="form-label">Nº. Recibo</label>
        <input type="text" name="recibo" class="form-control">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
        <label class="form-label">Saldo</label>
        <input type="text" name="saldo" class="form-control">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row justify-content-md-center">
    <div class="col-md-8">
        <br><button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Guardar</button><br>  
    </div>
</div>
</div>
</form>
```

El codigo `javascript` usando `jquery`:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#nombre').autocomplete({
        source: function(request, response){
            $.ajax({
                url:"{{route('cuentas.search')}}",
                dataType: 'json',
                data: {
                    term: request.term
                },
                success: function(data){
                    response(data)
                }
            });
        }
    });
</script>
```

el controlador:

```
 public function search(Request $request){
    $term =$request->get('term');
    $querys = Cuenta::where('nombre', 'LIKE', '%'. $term . '%')->get();
    $data = [];
    foreach ($querys as $query) {
        $data[] = [
            'label' => $query->nombre
        ];
    }
    return $data;
}
```

Comment: obtén el resultado de la consulta y solo coge el primer registro

Answer (score 1):

Puedes probar cambiando la consulta de tu controlador para agrupar los mismos nombres en un solo registro. Más o menos así:

```
 public function search(Request $request){
    $term =$request->get('term');
    $querys = Cuenta::where('nombre', 'LIKE', '%'. $term . '%')->groupBy('nombre')->get();
    $data = [];
    foreach ($querys as $query) {
        $data[] = [
            'label' => $query->nombre
        ];
    }
    return $data;
}
```